# .upa and .upb files

Tags: pdftex

Since a few days ervery time I compile a document I have been receiving .upa and .ubp files. Before that never happened. My question is in two parts:

- Why .upa and .upb files are produces and for what reason?
- Which setting / package causes this production of .upa and .upb files?

Comment: If you would make a MWE, I'm pretty sure you could find which of the packages you use is involved.

Comment: Are you using pdfcomment?

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz Thank you, yes, it was pdfcomment. Your LaTeX knowledge is just so huge, thank you for you tremendous support!